# jQuery $(this).closest show & hide

Tags: jquery

I've got a table with multiple rows. In each row is a Show Details Button and a Hide Details button. On clicking show details I want the hide details button to only show for the specific row. I thought the .closest() function would work but it hasn't yet.

Here is the HTML

```
<table>
    <tr id="1">
      <td><button class='view'>View Details</button><button class='hide' style='display:none;'>Hide Details</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
      <td><button class='view'>View Details</button><button class='hide' style='display:none;'>Hide Details</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$(".view").click(function() {   
    $("#patient").show("");
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest(".hide").show();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you binding after the dom is ready? Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".view").click(function() {   
        $("#patient").show("");
        $(this).hide().next().show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

`.closest` looks at the current element and its parents only. You'd have to do this like:

```
$(this).parent().find('.hide');
```

or

```
$(this).siblings('.hide');
```

Answer (score 2):

try next() instead of closest().

http://api.jquery.com/next/
http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

When using closest, you usually give it some additional info like a class to look for, or something else.